# Why does the following simple method return NaN (not a number) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, object, data-structures, methods

[image: My JS code]

Shown above is a simple JS code I ran on the Chrome JS console. But When I accessed the simple add method I have created in the object name 'obj', it returns NaN as shown below. Can someone tell me why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Please provide actual code, not a screenshot

Comment: `3 + undefined` evaluates to `NaN`. Did you mean `obj.add(1, 2)` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the first argument is `1+2` (`=3`) and the second argument is `undefined`

`3+undefined=NaN`

Try `console.log`:

```js
function add(x,y) {
   console.log(x,y,x+y)
   return x + y
}
console.log(add(1+2))
console.log(add(1,2))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing the second argument, so javascript interprets it as undefined.

```
var obj = {
  add: function(x, y) {
    return x + y;
  }
}

obj.add(1, 2) // 1 + 2 = 3
obj.add(1+2) // 1+2 + undefined = 3 + undefined = NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

because you should pass obj.add(1,2) not (1+2)

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing arguments correctly [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvMEB.png) "y" is never passed in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not passing 2nd argument.

> obj.add(1+2) is same as obj.add(3, undefined)

It will work if you pass like this-

> obj.add(1, 2);